# Fill ComboBox with db data in TreeTableView

Tags: java, database, javafx, combobox, javafx-8

I've the following code to make a column in my `TreeTableView`:

```
JFXTreeTableColumn<Employee, String> col = new JFXTreeTableColumn<>("marital status");
col.setPrefWidth(150);
col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Employee, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
    @Override
    public ObservableValue<String> call(TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Employee, String> param) {
        return param.getValue().getValue().getEmployee().getMaritalStatus().nameProperty();
    }
});

MaritalStatusDAO maritalStatusDAO = new MaritalStatusDAO();

ObservableList<MaritalStatus> obsListMaritalStatus = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
obsListMaritalStatus.addAll(maritalStatusDAO.getEstadosCivis());

col.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTreeTableCell.forTreeTableColumn(obsListMaritalStatus));
```

But I'm having an error in `col.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTreeTableCell.forTreeTableColumn(obsListMaritalStatus));` line, I think the error happens because I inform that the table data will be of type Employee and in the ComboBox the data should be of type MatrialStatus (I want to do this because I need the `id` of the item in ComboBox and not just the String) and if I make an `ObservableList<String>` it works correctly, however I need it to be with the Object, so how can I do this?

(I was following this tutorial: [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BNvVSU9nHDY))

**EDIT**: The program does not compile, and what pops up when I hover over the `setCellFactory` word, the message is (If the ObservableList type is MaritalStatus): `setCellFactory(Callback<TreeTableColumn<Employee,String>,Tre‌​eTableCell<Employee,‌​String>>) in the type TreeTableColumn<Employee,String> is not applicable for the arguments (Callback<TreeTableColumn<Object,MaritalStatus>,TreeTableCel‌​l<Object,MaritalStat‌​us>>)`

Comment: `I'm having an error` - is there a stack trace you could include in your post?

Comment: Are you importing `javafx.scene.control.cell.ComboBoxTreeTableCell`?

Comment: Could you edit your question to include that error message, since that's really what the question is attempting to resolve?

Comment: Ok, I'll remove some comments to make it more organized

Comment: For future reference, you can leave the comments and all image you had added, but just add an "edit:" or something like that. That way my comments (or any others) don't seem completely random :)

Comment: Oh, sorry. I did this because in other questions I was advised to do this

Comment: Your `Employee` class has a `getEmployee()` method and the returned object has a `getMaritalStatus()` method which returns a object containing a `name` property which is what you want to edit? Seriously? What about simply giving the `Employee` a `ObjectProperty<MaritalStatus> maritalStatusProperty()`???

Comment: BTW: I just took a short look at this tutorial video. What this guy is doing around 4:40 is definitely not how properties should be used. If the rest of the tutorial is of the same quality, I recommend forgetting everything "learned" from that tutorial and using a tutorial created by someone who knows the basics instead of a tutorial by someone who simply throws things together the way they seem to work for him... E.g. take a look at the `Employee` class in this tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/tree-table-view.htm for a proper use of properties.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with JavaFX, however I can try to address the compile error you're getting.

You start out with `final TreeTableColumn<Employee, String> col`. In the documentation for `TreeTableColumn`, we get an explanation of the type parameters:

```
...final TreeTableColumn<S, T>...
Type Parameters:
    <S> The type of the TableView generic type (i.e. S == TableView<S>)
    <T> The type of the content in all cells in this TableColumn.
```

In your code, you've chosen `Employee` to be the `TableView` generic type (ie. `S`), and `String` as the type for the content in each cell of the column (ie. `T`).

Similarly, in your anonymous `Callback` implementation, you've correctly used `Employee` and `String` as the `TableView` and `TreeTableColumn` types respectively, and so on.

Moving on to the trouble spot, take a look at the method signature of `forTreeTableColumn`:

```
public static <S,T> Callback<TreeTableColumn<S,T>, TreeTableCell<S,T>> forTreeTableColumn(
        final ObservableList<T> items)
```

...where `T` is "The type of the elements contained within the TreeTableColumn." - in your case this is `String`.

That is why when you change the parameterized type of your `ObservableList` to `String`, the error goes away.

If the type of that column really should be `MaritalStatus` as you've mentioned, then you'll also need to fix the types on the `TreeTableColumn`, `CellDataFeatures`, etc. so that `T` is `MaritalStatus` and not `String`:

```
TreeTableColumn<Employee, MaritalStatus> col = new TreeTableColumn<>("marital status");
col.setPrefWidth(150);
col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Employee, MaritalStatus>, ObservableValue<MaritalStatus>>() {
    @Override
    public ObservableValue<MaritalStatus> call(TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Employee, MaritalStatus> param) {
        // Probably won't compile here now because the type of 'param' has changed
        return param.getValue().getValue().getEmployee().getMaritalStatus().nameProperty();
    }
});

MaritalStatusDAO maritalStatusDAO = new MaritalStatusDAO();

ObservableList<MaritalStatus> obsListMaritalStatus = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
obsListMaritalStatus.addAll(maritalStatusDAO.getEstadosCivis());

col.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTreeTableCell.forTreeTableColumn(obsListMaritalStatus));
```

I haven't watched the entirety of the tutorial you linked, but hopefully that helps explain why and how you can use `ObservableList<MaritalStatus>` instead of `ObservableList<String>`.

I've pointed out that you'll likely get a compilation error inside the `call` method now. Your parameter type has changed, so you would need to reevaluate what needs to be done inside the method to return an object of the new expected type (`Observable<MaritalStatus>`).

Again, I'm not sure if this will functionally achieve what you're looking for, but it should get you going in the right direction in terms of the use of generics here.

Take a look at [Oracle's Java Documentation on generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) for a better explanation of how generic types work in Java.